# How can I use MySQL and PHP to increase a value daily?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm wondering how I can increase the value for the user by 10 daily or each time they log in?

I'm relatively new to PHP and have only made a login and signup system and need help learning.

Comment: You can probably handle both from your PHP application code.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: log in -- do it with the log in code; daily -- use a cron job

Answer (score 1):

You need a new column for each user in the database, this will store the value. You also need to store the last time they logged in (so you'll need a column for that). Each time they log in, in the login PHP code check to see if the current date is at least one day ahead of the last time they logged in. If it is, increase the value by ten; otherwise, leave it.